# Error when exporting

Tags: export, warning-messages, animation, video, error-tracking

Imagine I have a list of plots, call it `frames`, and I rasterize them in order to have a smoother exported video, like so

```
rasterizedframes = Image /@ frames;
Export["movie.mp4", rasterizedframes, ImageResolution -> 3000, Antialiasing -> True]]
```

This usually works and I get a decent looking video. However, recently I've been trying to export larger lists of images (`frames` with length beyond 1000), and exportation always fails, followed by the following message

[image]

Any idea why this happens? I couldn't figure out the meaning of this error message.
Unfortunately I can't reproduce the specific plots in `frames` here.

Comment: This one is for devs but in the meantime: (1) Reduce `ImageResolution` to (say) 50, can you still export 1000 frames? (2) Find out at how many frames the error is triggered for a res of 1000; use binary search (3) Find out whether experiments 1,2 interact?